# Not Getting Payment options in CCAvenue

Tags: java, javascript, payment-gateway, ccavenue

here i am trying to integrate my website with ccAvenue, here i downloaded integration kit from my merchent account and get all required keys(accss_code,working key, marchentid), but here i am not able to get payment options while testing the url in my site.
 the url is `

```
 var jsonData;
 var access_code = "xxxxxxxx" // shared by CCAVENUE 
 var amount="10.00";
 var currency="INR";


  $.ajax({
       url:'https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=getJsonData&access_code='+access_code+'&currency='+currency+'&amount='+amount,
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       jsonp: false,
       jsonpCallback: 'processData',
       success: function (data) { 
             jsonData = data;
             // processData method for reference
             alert("data");
             console.log(data);
 }
 });
```

`

It gives me error response as a

> Invalid URl

. please any one tell me where i went wrong? here i am getting the following result in console

> Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=getJsonData&access_code=xxxxxxxx&currency=INR&amount=10.00&_=xxxxx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved problem,  Here they provided 3 types of integration kits

> 1)CUSTOM_CHECKOUT_FORM_KIT
>
> 2)IFRAME_KIT
>
> 3)NON_SEAMLESS_KIT

So here i used Custom_checkout kit, after i called them, they suggested that use NON_SEAMLESS_KIT. now its working file